# Populating Two Large Vectors at Run Time Start

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures

I'm building a virtual game economy and the first task of my program is to populate two vectors of structs with items retrieved from a database. My two structs are listed below.

Item objects are created for a finite set of items in the database; PItems hold all items from the database. The purpose of PItems are to prune the database every so often. Loading them once into a vector eliminates the need for subsequent read operations during run time.

The problem I have is running both methods in sequence. If I call both functions after the start of the program, the Name values are populated with garbage characters. If I call only one of the functions (either one), then the vector is populated fine and I can iterate over all the structures and print the names fine. I'm curious if this is due to the dynamic allocation of vectors. Maybe I have some sort of race condition. Interestingly, all integer values are populated successfully if I run both functions, but never const char* data types unless I call only one function.

As it stands, I can only call one function or the other, but not both.

I've tried putting them on different threads and joining them after completion, but haven't been successful thus far. I've also tried create a struct containing vectors instead of multi-dimensional vectors, but that was unsuccessful as well.

Item Structures

```
struct Item
{
  const char* Name = "";
  uint16 ID    = 0;
  uint32 Price = 0;
  uint8  Stack = 0;
};

struct PItem
{
  const char* Name = "";
  uint16 ID = 0;
};
```

Routine to Load Items into Vectors

```
extern CData* DB;
extern thread_local sqldata* SQL;

auto LoadBotItems(std::vector<std::vector<Item>> &Items) -> void
{
  Message::Status("Loading item lists");

  std::vector<Item> Ammo;
  std::vector<Item> Armor;
  std::vector<Item> Common;
  std::vector<Item> Food;
  std::vector<Item> Materials;
  std::vector<Item> Weapons;

  qresult Q = DB->Query(SQL, "SELECT Name, ID, Price, Qty, Cat FROM bot_data;");

  if (Q == PASS && DB->NumRows(SQL) != 0)
  {
    while (DB->NextRow(SQL) == PASS)
    {
      Item I;

      I.Name    = (const char*)DB->GetText(SQL, 0);
      I.ID      = (uint16)DB->GetUInt(SQL, 1);          
      I.Price   = (uint32)DB->GetUInt(SQL, 2);
      I.Stack   = (uint8 )DB->GetUInt(SQL, 3);
      uint8 Cat = (uint8 )DB->GetUInt(SQL, 4);

      if (Cat == 1)             // Ammo
        Ammo.push_back(I);
      else if (Cat == 2)        // Common
        Common.push_back(I);
      else if (Cat == 3)        // Weapon
        Weapons.push_back(I);
      else if (Cat == 4)        // Armor
        Armor.push_back(I);
      else if (Cat == 5)        // Materials
        Materials.push_back(I);
      else if (Cat == 6)        // Food
        Food.push_back(I);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Message::Error("Could not load bot items!");
    return;
  }

  Items.push_back(Ammo);
  Items.push_back(Armor);
  Items.push_back(Common);
  Items.push_back(Food);
  Items.push_back(Materials);
  Items.push_back(Weapons);

  Message::Status("Bot items have been loaded.");
}

auto LoadPurgeItems(std::vector<PItem> &PItems) -> void
{
  qresult A = DB->Query(SQL, "SELECT ID, Name FROM Items WHERE Cat != 0;");

  if (A == PASS && DB->NumRows(SQL) != 0)
  {
    while (DB->NextRow(SQL) == PASS)
    {
      PItem I;
      I.ID   = (uint16)DB->GetUInt(SQL, 0);
      I.Name = (const char*)DB->GetText(SQL, 1);
      PItems.push_back(I);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Message::Error("Could not load purge items!");
    return;
  }

  Message::Status("Purge items have been loaded.");
}
```

I'm trying to get both vectors populated at run time start. Am I not using the most appropriate data structures for this? Or is it an error in my logic of loading them in this manner? Do I need to implement threads and mutex?

Comment: If you are using `std::vector`, why are you not using `std:string`?

Comment: Tried that, still works the same way. Besides, my CData class returns int8* for text results and other things are using that data type so left it as it is.

Comment: If I knew what your database code was, I would look up the `GetText` documentation. If it returns `char *`, you should be able to assign directly to a `std::string`. If you don't want to use `std::string`, then it should not be `const char *`. At that point, assuming that the API "owns" that pointer, you need to allocate memory and copy the data into that new memory.

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying. I'm pointing to blocks of memory that were probably freed back to the system and overwritten, hence the garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I couldn't covert to std::string for some reason. Still figuring out why. For my purpose, though, I changed const char* Name to char[20] Name and used strcpy. Worked like a charm after that.

Edit:

It's been a while since I posted this, but as I recall it was an issue with ownership and pointers. I needed to make a full copy of the data at the memory address at the time the function executed. Afterward, ownership was lost and I was pointing to values that had been overwritten.